# Can we calculate energy of light using wave theory? And will it be the same as $E=h\nu$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, wave-particle-duality

From wave theory we got that energy of wave is given by $E = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon |\vec{E}|^2$ and from particle theory $E=h\nu$. So can we use wave theory to calculate energy of wave?

Comment: The energy is $h \nu$ *times the number of photons*. If you use wave theory, an estimate of this number is all you'll get.

Comment: So here the no of photons is proportional to |E|^2 and not v?

Comment: The number of photons is proportional to $|E|^2$ and I don't know what you mean by v.

Comment: By v i meant frequency. But i understood my doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quantized electromagnetic field the operators of the electric and magnetic field are expressed in terms of the photon creation/annihilation operators $a_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}^\dagger, a_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}$ (see [Wkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Quantization_of_EM_field)). The familiar classical expression for the energy of the field can then be expressed in terms of the photon number operators, $n_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}=a_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}$, with every photon mode having energy $h\nu_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}n_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}$ - see [this section of the cited Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Hamiltonian_of_the_field).